# how to read data from sqlite database in phonegap?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

i use phonegap for my application. i create sqlite database and copied it on memory card.

Is it possible to read data from the database on a memory card

thank you and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't read the database from a custom path. The PhoneGap/Cordova expects the database to be in particular location. If not present, it will create a new database.

But you can move the content to the expected location and start working on it.

Some links to help are:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/7/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Comment: Is it possible to copy a database to /data/data/app_name/app_database?
i do not use eclips for create and edit file.
i use cmd and for edit use visual studio.